# How to get this node ID by cURL in PHP?

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I have some file save on unkownNodeId and only know that in range 0 to 5
http://example.com/api/node/fileId/unkownNodeId

When I send request to get fileId, for example is 2233
http://example.com/api/node/2233/unkownNodeId

I always have to try 1 by 1 like this http://example.com/api/node/2233/0 1 2 3 4 5
When I get wrong unkownNodeId, server only response as json array `{"status":false}`
Is there anyway to send request by curl, then stop on right nodeId?

Comment: Yes its possible to do by curl. Did you try some curl call? You can use Curl in a for loop to achieve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't think curl can do that by itself, but use a scripting language in combination with curl, it's trivial. for example with php-cli:

```
php -r '$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
for($i=0;$i<6;++$i){
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://example.com/api/node/2233/".$i);
    $ret=curl_exec($ch);
    if($ret!=="{\"status\":false}"){
        echo "correct node id: $i";
        return;
    }
}'
```

output: `correct node id: 0`